# Access a tab element in tab bar controller and change value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

How do you access an element in a tab bar controller and change its value? For instance i want to access a particular view controller in a tab bar controller and change a property in the view controller. Been stuck with this for a while. I have called tab bar init with nib name and initliased the tab bar. Now i need to know how to access one view in it. I tried

```
UITabBarController *newTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlaceTabBarControllers" bundle:nil];
[newTabBar.selectedViewController setView:listViewController.view];
```

but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIViewController *viewController = [newTabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Yes did that. However it doesnt do anything. i try to print what object is at index 0/1/2 it gives null.

Comment: If you have a xib for your tabBarController, your viewControllers should be set there. I think that you have forget something there.

Comment: I am using storyboards the new feature in iOS5? I dont have a class for the tab bar controller but i do have views which are connected to it.